# Setting the display to 1600 x 900 in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, settings, vmware, resolution

I am using VMware fusion on my mac.  I would like to change the res to 1600 x 900 in windows 10 but the options does not seem to be there.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.  thanks

Comment: I have never used VMware. In VirtualBox you can tweak config files to setup your custom resolution. Have you tried this? https://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.ws.using.doc%2FGUID-09956D63-AB96-4610-874D-B80CDA9D5734.html

Comment: Thank you that was a big help in finding an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using multiple monitors so within display settings on my mac, I change the display to 1600x900 to the left monitor.  I then went to my VM settings and under 'Virtual Machine Resolution' set the full screen option to 'stretch the vm in the screen'.  Set the vm to full screen within that left monitor and then go check in windows what the resolution is, it is now 1600x900!